# django - what's the proper way of passing the "request" parameter to a custom template tag

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I created a custom template tag that I want to use on every page on my web site.  I have a function **get_ip** inside the custom template tag that needs the **request** parameter in order to get the IP address from the user. See below:

**myapp/templatetags/header_tags.py**

---

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
...
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

@register.inclusion_tag('template.html', takes_context = True)
def user_ip(context):
    request = context['request']
    ip = get_ip(request)      
    return render_to_response('template.html',locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**template.html**

---

```
   {{ ip }}
```

**my_main_template.html**

---

```
{% load header_tags %}
{% user_ip %}
```

For some reason my the **ip** is not sowing on my main template. My function **get_ip** works if used the regular way on views.py page a template but for some reason is not showing when is used from the custom template tag above. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not supposed to actually *render* the template in an inclusion tag - the decorator does that for you. You just return the context that should be used to render the template you've specified.

Comment: So instead of using "return render_to_response(...)" should I just use return {'ip':ip } ?

Answer (score 1):

Try somenting like this.

```
@register.inclusion_tag('template.html', takes_context = True)
def user_ip(context):
    return {'ip': get_ip(context['request'])}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your inclusion tag should return a context to be rendered to a template, not `render_to_response`. Might look like this:

```
def user_ip(context):
    my_context = {}
    request = context['request']
    my_context['ip'] = get_ip(request)      
    return my_context

register.inclusion_tag('template.html', takes_context = True)(user_ip)
```